# How to test if file size is increased by Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to test if a Class `Foo` writes a error log by size increasing.

I adjusted a [Rspec example](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/expect-change) like this.

```
it "should increase a error log size" do
  expect{Foo.write_error_log}.to change{File.size(ERROR_LOG)}.from(0).to(1)
end
```

But I don't know how much size will be increased by error output.

What should I write instead of `from(0).to(1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you already have a fairly good idea of (at least) how long an error log entry will be. If that's the case, your test example can make a good use of "by_at_least."

```
it "should increase a error log size" do
  expect{Foo.write_error_log}.to change{File.size(ERROR_LOG)}.by_at_least({your expectations})
end
```

Just to differentiate this from other log entries. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `from` and `to`

```
it "should increase a error log size" do
  expect{Foo.write_error_log}.to change{File.size(ERROR_LOG)}
end
```